# Figuring out which line of code is generating SQL exception

Tags: java, playframework

I have an Actor (Play Framework, Java) for doing some database data import at regular intervals. This actor calls various other classes that do the importing, persisting, etc. My current problem is that I'm unable to figure out the exact line number and file that is generating SQL exceptions. For instance, I get errors like this:

```
[info] application - javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint\n   Detail: Failing row contains (266, null, null, null).]
[info] application - Starting persisting of customer id 29917837
[error] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into emails (email, domain, user_id) values (null,null,null);
throws exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (268, null, null, null).
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (268, null, null, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:495)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:441)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Naturally, I can look at the error message and see that something somewhere is trying to persist my Email model without populating it. Right now the code base is really small (~200-300 lines) and I can guess pretty accurately where this is coming from. But shouldn't the framework also report line numbers? Or perhaps this is what happens when actors are used, because they are somehow, kind of, outside the system and all?

Comment: In fact you do have line numbers for most of your classes (having line numbers in compiled java code is optional). But, is this your entire stack trace? Which method/s is using reflection to invoke HikariProxyPreparedStatement?

Comment: @SergioMontoro Yes,this is the entire stack trace. Actually I'm using the Play Framework, which uses Akka actors to schedule tasks. Beyond that, I have little clue who does what, but it seems like the framework is using reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a framework that executes it's queries using reflection, which makes debugging quite difficult. I don't know the specific framework you are using, but it's quite possible that it has configuration that can be set to make debugging this kind of thing easier.

If not, or it's your own code that is using reflection, you can catch the exception, wrap it, and rethrow it from within the "outer" code, the code that is executing the reflection operation. This will give you an extra stack trace with the exact location in your code that it is happening.

For example, you can do this with your wrapper code:

```
try {
     this.custPersister.persist(customer);
} catch (Exception e) {
     throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Just make sure this exception is caught in the appropriate place in your outer code, and the stack trace logged.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I'm actually using the Play Framework. I had tagged my question, and have now added the framework name to my question for greater clarity. In fact, earlier I wasn't even getting this much from exception reporting. It was only after I wrapped the Actor code (see http://pastebin.com/RXtQUye7) that I started getting at least this much.

Comment: So you are already most of the way there. Just change your wrapper code as I will explain above. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It improved a lot! (see http://pastebin.com/9eEDnSZ9) The problem is, all it now gives me is which line of the Actor caused the error. I still don't know which class caused the exception and why. But I guess that's how Actors in Play Framework work . . . I mean Actors really are supposed to be disjoint units and all. But tell me, why did this simple change produce so much more information? I'll then accept this as the answer. :-)

Comment: Your stack trace tells you that it is happening in your UserImportActor triggering it, which is called by your MailBox class. That's quite a bit of detail. To go further, we would need to know a lot more about what is happening in your code. As far as why this change helped, each time an exception is thrown, the current location in code (the stack trace) is captured in the exception object. Wrapping it around another exception gives that "Cause by..." info you see in the logs.